# How to test my code against various cultures/regions

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, regional-settings

I have following piece of code in my application.

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
RegionInfo currentRegion = new RegionInfo(currentCulture.LCID);

// various properties of currentRegion is used in my program based on culture info
```

I would like to test currentRegion for various regions/culture. What settings (in windows server 2012) I have to change to get different different values of culture? Are these settings per user or per machine? Does the machine require a reboot after changing these settings?

Comment: `CurrentCulture` uses the operating system's "User Locale" setting. The knob used to live in the "Regional Options" control panel. I can't remember what they changed it to in Windows 7, let alone WIndows 8. Look around, I'm sure you cannot miss it. Note that with version 4.6 of the Framework and later, this is a read-only property, so you can just twiddle it at will for your process.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` has a setter. You can set it to whatever you like and test your code?